What are the maximum dimensions of NFC reader antennas?
For my project, I need to detect small NFC tags (like this one: URL) at a 1 cm range on a surface that is roughly 20 x 10 cm. My initial thought was to use an NFC reader with an antenna of approximately the same size (20 x 10 cm) to cover the entire area.
However, after doing some research (since I have limited experience with NFC antenna design), I’ve noticed that NFC reader antennas tend to be much smaller : around 4 x 4 cm in most cases. I’m wondering if there is a specific reason for this, or if there is a maximum allowable size for NFC reader antennas ?
Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you !

I never remember which bands these are using but perhaps there are multiple allowed frequency bands? It's all about multiples of the wave length.

The generally small size of NFC antenna is probably due to the fact that most of them fit in small things - phones, POS terminals, next to card slots in parking machines etc. 20 x 10 cms is a huge area for a space constrained device.
The wavelength of the 13.5 MHz used is a bit over 22 m, so you will have no trouble creating an antenna of that area with one or even a few turns.
For reassurance, look at the size of the NFC loops at the doors of your local tag-protected shops, often 20 x 50 cms or more.
